# Connecting Web App to new VPN in Azure

Tags: azure, web-applications, virtual-network

Is it possible to connect a Web App to a 'Virtual network' (*not* a 'Virtual network (classic)') in Azure - and if so how.

I virtual network, with a virtual network gateway connected but there does not seem to be any way to configure a point-to-site connection, and my network does not show up under the web app network configuration.

**Note**: this is through the new portal.azure.com as opposed to manage.azure.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Point-to-site connections are not currently available in the Azure Resource Manager. You'll need to use classic networking until it's available.

You can [connect a classic virtual network and virtual network with a site-to-site VPN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-vnet-vnet-rm-ps/)